# How to Create Multi-layer Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

Thank you for any help I'm given in advance with this! I have been given the python code for a simple single layer perceptron with the task to alter the code so it is a multi-layer perceptron. I'm still very new to all of this, but from what I understand the repeating feed-forward and back-propagation cycle is what creates the hidden layers. Given the follow code, what should be altered to help create these hidden layers?

```
# Creating a numerically stable logistic s-shaped definition to call
def sigmoid(x):
    x = np.clip(x, -500, 500)
    if x.any()>=0:
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))
    else:
        return np.exp(x)/(1 + np.exp(x))

# define the dimentions and set the weights to random numbers
def init_parameters(dim1, dim2=1,std=1e-1, random = True):
    if(random):
        return(np.random.random([dim1,dim2])*std)
    else:
        return(np.zeros([dim1,dim2]))
    
# Single layer network: Forward Prop
# Passed in the weight vectors, bias vector, the input vector and the Y
def fwd_prop(W1, bias, X, Y):

    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + bias # dot product of the weights and X + bias
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)  # Uses sigmoid to create a predicted vector

    return(A1)    

#Single layer network: Backprop
def back_prop(A1, W1, bias, X, Y):

    m = np.shape(X)[1] # used the calculate the cost by the number of inputs -1/m
   
    # Cross entropy loss function
    cost = (-1/m)*np.sum(Y*np.log(A1) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A1)) # cost of error
    dZ1 = A1 - Y                                            # subtract actual from pred weights
    dW1 = (1/m) * np.dot(dZ1, X.T)                          # calc new weight vector
    dBias = (1/m) * np.sum(dZ1, axis = 1, keepdims = True)  # calc new bias vector
    
    grads ={"dW1": dW1, "dB1":dBias} # Weight and bias vectors after backprop
    
    return(grads, cost)

def run_grad_desc(num_epochs, learning_rate, X, Y, n_1):
    
    n_0, m = np.shape(X)
    
    W1 = init_parameters(n_1, n_0, True)
    B1 = init_parameters(n_1,1, True)
    
    loss_array = np.ones([num_epochs])*np.nan # resets the loss_array to NaNs
    
    for i in np.arange(num_epochs):
        A1 = fwd_prop(W1, B1, X, Y)                # get predicted vector
        grads, cost = back_prop(A1, W1, B1, X, Y)    # get gradient and the cost from BP 
        
        W1 = W1 - learning_rate*grads["dW1"]    # update weight vector LR*gradient*[BP weights]
        B1 = B1 - learning_rate*grads["dB1"]    # update bias LR*gradient[BP bias]
        
        loss_array[i] = cost                    # loss array gets cross ent values
        
        parameter = {"W1":W1, "B1":B1}           # assign 
    
    return(parameter, loss_array)
```

We've also been asked to be able to adjust for the nodes in a hidden layer. Being honest, I am completely lost here and am not clear on what the nodes even represent, so help here would be appreciated as well. Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this network is not even single layer. Normally "single layer" means one layer of hidden neurons. This network outputs the activations of what would normally be the hidden layer.

My advice to you would be to start studying the basics of neural networks. There are lots of great resources, including on Youtube. For backpropagation, a good place to start is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-backpropagation-algorithm-7bb3aa2f95fd)

Also note that if you are in a hurry, using autograd tools like Tensorflow or Pytorch takes care of the differentiation for you. Of course, if you are doing this to learn the details of neural networks, then building one from scratch is much better.